# WPF-Listview Column Header Resize with Custom Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, columnheader

I am new in WPF ,In the WPF application I used Listview Gridview  for display the data.
I have customized the style of Listview, Now I want to change the default glossy blue color of mouse hover effect for Listview Gridview Column Header

I googled and change the style of Column header but I cant resize the column of listview(Cant resize  the column header using mouse dragging).

Is therer any solution for the same ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

If you change the template of a column header (As I assume you did when changing the style), you are essentially rebuilding it. So you must rebuild all the functionalities of the original template.

You can get the full template [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates).

But to the point of your question, make sure to add the following Style:

```
<Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderGripper"
   TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="Width"
      Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                       EndPoint="0,1">
                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                      Offset="0.0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                      Offset="1.0" />
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            Background="Transparent">
                    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 Width="1"
                 Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                       StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black"
                  Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="White"
                  Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then, in your custom style, make sure the ControlTemplate has a Grid in it, with the first item being what ever custom design you want, and the second being the header gripper.

Here's an example:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomGridViewColumnHeader" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                <Grid>
                    <!-- My Custom Template -->
                    <Border Background="#FF3B4A51" Height="35">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" Margin="4,0,0,0" Padding="0,5" />
                    </Border>

                    <!-- The gripper / header resizer -->
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper"
             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
             Margin="0,0,-9,0"
             Style="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderGripper}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <!-- Other properties you want to change ... -->
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Three hours trying to restyle and overwrite the local property just to keep the columns resize... thanks!!!